# Menu supposed to hide onmouseout but it hide onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button and a menu. The button on mouse over shows the menu. I've coded when the mouse leaves the menu to hide itself, but it hides before the mouse goes over it. Help?

```js
function showMenu() {
  var menuBar = document.getElementById("menu");

  menuBar.style.display = "block";

}

function hideMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<a id="menu_button" onmouseover="showMenu()"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/mRIyhW8.png" class="menu_button" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/zSPpoVX.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/mRIyhW8.png'" /></a>

<div id="menu" onmouseout="hideMenu()">
  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Adding a z-index: 2; in my css solved the problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you change the link of the image to a full link so we can test ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif There.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mouseleave` because:

> The mouseout event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child
>   elements as well the selected element.

Update:

1. changed the size of the `menu_button` to avoid triggering outside
   the image.
2. Added css to #menu, now starts hidden.
3. Added a `mouseleave` to `menu_button` to hide when leaving the
   image.

```js
document.getElementById("menu_button").addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
});

document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
});

document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
});

document.getElementById("menu_button").addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#menu_button {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#menu_button img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#menu {
  border: solid 1px;
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<a id="menu_button"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/mRIyhW8.png" class="menu_button" /></a>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Funny think the menubar does not disappear when i leave it. I see that it works here, but not on my site.

Comment: @BillHicks I've updated with some changes to make it work better. If that won't do I'll need to see the rest of the code in your site.

Comment: @BillHicks I seeing what I've changed doesn't work well, sorry, I have to fix it.

Comment: @BillHicks Fixed, hope it works in your site, remember to copy the css styles.

Answer (score 0):

onmouseout event is triggered when the mouse over the UL element. It it complex to solve this problem with pure javascript. Jquery has mouseenter and mouseleave methods.

```
    $("#menu_button").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#menu").show();
    });
    $("#menu").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Comment: I've already tried jquery sir, and it doesn't work at all for some reason, and yeah I've included the library.